# Tried deleting a file using vb script from shared drive

Tags: vbscript

Tried deleting a file using vb script from shared drive using following code but wasn't able to do it.

```
Option Explicit

Dim filesys

Set filesys=Createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If filesys.FileExists("""G:\Data_Center\vb test\reports\test.pdf""") Then
filesys.DeleteFile"""G:\Data_Center\vb test\reports\test.pdf"""

End If
```

Comment: Post your error message.  When you run this in a command prompt, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the extra quotation marks, should work fine, as long as the file exists...

```
Dim filesys

Set filesys = Createobject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If filesys.FileExists("G:\Data_Center\vb test\reports\test.pdf") Then
  filesys.DeleteFile "G:\Data_Center\vb test\reports\test.pdf"
End If

Set filesys = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you it work but when I tried deleting a file which has space in between the words it did not work. Something like: ABC xyz .PDF